# While solving for $nP5 = 42 \cdot nP3$, $n > 4$

Tags: permutations

...if we cancel out $n!$ on both sides we get to a complex quadratic which gives a wrong result. But, if we cancel out the $(n-5)!$ and $(n-3)!$ on their respective sides of the equation and then solve the quadratic and use the constraint $n>4$ we arrive at an answer of $n = 10$. Why does the first approach not give the same result? I am completely baffled...is it to do with cancelling out the $n!$ on both sides or is it something else altogether? Please help. Thanks

$nP5 = 42. nP3$, therefore $$\frac{n!}{(n-5)!} = 42 \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-3)!}$$...if we cancel out $n!$ on both the sides, then we get: $$1 = 42(n-5)(n-4)$$ ... the solution of which leads to a quadratic with relatively large numbers and so on and so forth...on the other hand, if we keep the respective sides of the equation separate and solve them, then we get: $$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=42. [n(n-1)(n-2)]$$ ...and since $n>4$, $n(n-1)(n-2)$ is not equal to zero, hence dividing both sides by that yields: $$(n-3)(n-4)=42$$ ...which gives an answer of $n=10$

Comment: nP5 = 42. nP3, therefore n!/(n-5)! = 42 [n!/(n-3)!]...if we cancel out n! on both the sides, then we get: 1 = 42(n-5)(n-4)...the solution of which leads to a quadratic with relatively large numbers and so on and so forth...on the other hand, if we keep the respective sides of the equation separate and solve them, then we get: n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=42. [n(n-1)(n-2)]...and since n>4, n(n-1)(n-2) is not equal to zero, hence dividing both sides by that yields: (n-3)(n-4)=42...which gives an answer of n=10

Comment: please format your question properly so people can more easily understand it and help you better. [Here's a mathjax tutorial :)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Can you tell us your complex quadratic because I am arriving at answer from both ways??

Comment: From your context I infer that "nP5" means "permutations of $n$ things arranged five at a time.  I can make the notation a bit more conventional if you confirm this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was probably assuming that $$\frac{(n-3)!}{(n-5)!}=\frac{1}{(n-4)(n-5)}$$
But notice that $n-5<n-3$ so $(n-3)!=(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)!$ and not $(n-5)!=(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)!$

Answer (score 0):

You wish to solve the equation
$$P(n, 5) = 42P(n, 3)$$
for $n > 4$.  Since 
$$P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$
you obtained
$$\frac{n!}{(n - 5)!} = 42 \cdot \frac{n!}{(n - 3)!}$$
Canceling $n!$ from each side of the equation yields
$$\frac{1}{(n - 5)!} = 42 \cdot \frac{1}{(n - 3)!}$$
Multiplying both sides of the equation by $(n - 3)!$ yields
$$\frac{(n - 3)!}{(n - 5)!} = 42$$
Expanding $(n - 3)!$ gives 
$$\frac{(n - 3)(n - 4)(n - 5)!}{(n - 5)!} = 42$$
Canceling yields
$$(n - 3)(n - 4) = 42$$
which is what you obtained using your other method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Taussig, kimW3 and fleablood! I see where I made the mistake. Thanks again for helping out. Cheers!

Comment: @DiveshM  If you only place your thanks under my comment, kimW3 and fleablood will not receive it.  Once you have acquired sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to thank those who provided helpful answers by casting an [up vote](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [accepting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) what you consider the best answer (assuming you have received one, of course).

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {(n-5)!}{(n-3)!} \ne (n-5)(n-4)$ as $(n-5)! \ne (n-3)!*[(n-4)(n-5)]$

Notice:  $(n-5) < (n-3)$ and $(n-3)! = 1*2*3.....*(n-5)*(n-4)*(n-3) = (n-5)!*[(n-4)(n-3)]$ .

And therefore $\frac {(n-5)!}{(n-3)!} = \frac 1{(n-4)(n-3)}$

This will give you the right answer.